# Memory pools and buffers C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, network-programming

I have a few questions about buffers and memory pools i would like to have answered.

Say i have a server, sending and receiving ~50-100+ msg / second. All msgs come in various sizes. How would you go about it to make the best of the memory management here ? My original plan was using fixed sized buffer nodes, and pool them, something like:

```
struct buffer{
    uint8_t  data[512];
    uint32_t end;
    buffer*  next;
}
buffer* b = pool_get_new_buffer();
```

So when a msg is sent, i create one or more buffers depending on the size and link them together. This way i dont have be afraid of fragmentation in the pool it self. (or thats atleast what i think). But on small msg, its a waste of space.

But reading more and more and checking out code on the internet, it looks like nobody uses this approach at all. So what would be a better approach ? Allocating memory from the pool depending on msg size ?

**EDIT**:
So what im after here is maybe a more indept comparison of the different approaches.

If i use the chained buffer approach im guessing i will keep fragmentation at its lowest but on the other hand i would guess that doing memcpy for every buffer in the chain comes at a cost as well. But then again, allocating a large enough buffer and doing a single memcpy must have its downsides as well, even though most people choose this approach anyway.

Comment: Your idea is good.  You just have to [extend it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation).  Your requirements seem like a [general allocator](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html).  Or maybe a [SLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocation) allocator if you need the memory to be initialized?

Comment: It's not too popular as Linux & BSD have pretty good allocators in already.  Windows default allocator is pretty terrible but since MSVC2010 they ship a pretty good one as part of the concurrency CRT.  Note the scheme you have mentioned is pretty much the one Linux & BSD use internally for sockets.

Comment: But why is it not popular ? because its harder to implement ? or because you dont gain that much in doing it this way ? Would be nice to know more specifically why one method is preferred over the other.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about wasting 512 bytes, or even 64kB, for messages that come at a rate of 100/second.  If you have an embedded microcontroller it's a different story.

Comment: @BenVoigt so what your saying is allocate when I need the memory, except on embedded systems? Because it will run on both type of platforms. More up to date hardware and embedded raspberry pi type of hardware.

Comment: @user2010820: Using a pool is fine, it does prevent fragmentation, heap processing, taking a shared lock on the process heap.  What I'm suggesting is to just make your blocks in the pool bigger, so most messages only need one.  Raspberry Pi has 512MB of RAM, a pool with 16 blocks of 64kB each is only 1MB.  Of course if you had a microcontroller with 256kB of RAM, then 512-byte blocks would make sense.  There's a tradeoff between speed, complexity and space used, and unless you're really short on space, use the extra space.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks for the answer, English is not my first language, so i dont always understand everything right away :)

Answer (score 1):

How about having a single buffer, say 0.5/1MB in size. This obviously depends on the target OS/device and possibly your maximum message size. Also, have your server include the packet size. Assuming your packet doesn't exceed the single buffer size you can download data into the buffer, process it and then mark the memory as available. I've used this approach for single client-server applications.